# How to handle response timeout in activeMq when using two queues for communication between two applications

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Say you have an Application A and an Application B that communicates together using ActiveMQ queues. The communication happens as below.

- A sends a request message to application B using the queue name
  **com.example.requestQueue**
- B consumes the message request from the queue name **com.example.requestQueue**
- B takes some time to handle the message request and then sends a
  response back to B using the response queue
  name **com.example.responseQueue**
- A consumes the response message from **com.example.responseQueue** queue and is done

If application B is always answering, there is no problem. 
But if for some reason the application B consumes a message from the request queue **com.example.requestQueue** and never puts a response message in the response queue **com.example.responseQueue**, application A will wait forever. 
Is there any way to solve this kind of problem please?

NB: The application A is written with Java and Camel and the application B is Written in C++

Thanks.

Comment: I think application B must have some sort of timeout, so it won't wait forever.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this option is not possible as application B is an external app that we buy, and we don't have source code to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camel supports request-reply flows in a single route (exchange pattern InOut), or you can break the request-reply into two separate routes (both exchange pattern InOnly) depending on your use case.

The request-reply patterns have timeout settings available based on the Camel component used. Add the timeout to the Application A Camel route request-reply.

ref: [SJMS Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sjms-component.html) - Newer JMS component

ref: [JMS Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html) - Original JMS component

ref: [Request Reply pattern](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/eips/requestReply-eip.html) - Info on InOut patterns

Side note--
If Application A is *also* expected to return something to a caller (ie a web app or a REST/SOAP client), than you would want to make sure you set the messaging response timeout to be lower than than the timeout used by the caller. This allows Application A to return a proper exception/error to the caller before the caller's timeout occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I'm new to JMS and Camel, I wasn't aware of the existence of JMSReplyTo, InOut and timeout. Now, I must just find a way to wire all this together :)